# Can have both client side click and click event handler in asp.net webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

**Question:**

I want to use both client side click event and click event handler on code. Is that a good approach?
 My code is:

```
 <dx:ASPxButton ID="edditsave" runat="server" Text="Save"  OnClick="edditsave_Click">
    <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {  ASPxPopupControl1.Show(); }" />
</dx:ASPxButton>
```

As i can't use this `ASPxPopupControl1.Show()` in event handler of button.And on other hand there is more than 100 lines having complex code in button event handler which i can't share here and i apologize for this. So friends can i use both `client side  click events` and `click event handler` of aspxbutton?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be a problem.  Any any website where an "are you sure" alert is used is essentially doing just this.